# upload file to server(IIS) by android phone

Tags: android

i googled about my problem but didn't find any thing.
I create a server in win 7 to uploading file from android phone to it.but I can't upload file.
I don't know Is server setting/config is true?![server1][1]

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/test.txt"; //complete path of file from your android device
        String urlServer = "http://www.rar.com/";// complete path of server
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        Log.i("*******urlServer**1**", "urlServer ");
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));
            Log.i("*******fileInputStream******", "sent: ");
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.i("*******HttpURLConnection**1**", "v ");
            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            Log.i("*******setRequestProperty**1**", "v ");
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            Log.i("*******DataOutputStream******", "DataOutputStream: ");
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            Log.i("*******lineEnd******", "writeBytes: ");
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.i("*******befwhile******", "byteread ");
            Log.i("*******byteread******", String.valueOf(bytesRead));

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            Log.i("*******befwhile******", "end while ");
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            Log.i("*******befwhile******", "twoHyphens ");
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = 0;
            String serverResponseMessage = "";
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("*******befwhile******", "getResponseCode1 ");
            serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("*******befwhile******", "getResponseMessage2 ");

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.i("*******Sending******", "sent: Final***");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("*******exception&&" + ex.toString(), ex.getMessage());
            //Exception handling
        }
```

also I don't meaning of outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
when I runned above code ,it run til 
Log.i("*******befwhile******", "twoHyphens ");
please help me!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation url.openConnection() return URLConnection not HttpURLConnection so the method getResponseCode() not exist. Your downcast to HttpURLConnection will not work. Also all data will be send after flush method.

Comment: thanks,do you have any simple example? physical path of "www.rar.com" is H:\AndS and i create  uploadedfile folder in that,Is it true?

Comment: where can I find uploaded file in server?where  is its path?